# How to make Search screen Netflix?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I would like to make search screen like Netflix,

Why search screen can see-through, I have to create stateless widget of the new screen or something?

[image: netflix searchscreen]

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

- You can use Stack widget.
- You can navigate a new page with PageRouteBuilder.

I've added an example for option 2 below.

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false,
        fullscreenDialog: true,
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
          return Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(color: Colors.black38),
              ListView(
                children: [
                  // Search Items..
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```